# Make query to three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

I want to make query to 3 different tables: two tables has relationship many-to-many and one table is intermediary table. Please take a look at DB-schema:

```
ROLE
-----------
+ role_id
+ role_name

ROLE_GROUP
-----------
+ role_id
+ entity_id
+ group_id

GROUP
-----------
+ group_id
+ group_desc
```

I need entity_id and group_desc as a result of a query. I try to make following but have incorrect result:

```
SELECT ROLE_GROUP.entity_id, GROUP.group_desc
FROM GROUP INNER JOIN ROLE_GROUP
ON GROUP.group_id=ROLE_GROUP.group_id
INNER JOIN ROLE
ON ROLE_GROUP.role_id=ROLE_role_id
WHERE ROLE.role_name='something';
```

Could you correct the query to get proper result?

If it is possible to make it through Hibernate's Criteria please post it.

Comment: `ROLE_GROUP.role_id=ROLE_role_id` change ROLE_role_id to ROLE.role_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select RG.ENTITY_ID, G.GROUP_DESC
  from ROLE R inner join ROLE_GROUP RG on R.ROLE_ID   = RG.ROLE_ID
              inner join GROUP G       on RG.GROUP_ID = G.GROUP_ID
 where R.ROLE_NAME = 'something';
```

Comment: Thank you! It is almost the same but the tables are noticed in opposite direction. Why doesn't it work in primary direction?

Comment: @aime Your primary table is `ROLE` from where you pickup the `ROLE_ID` based on the filter `R.ROLE_NAME = 'something'` and then move forward and pick linked records from other tables

Answer (score 1):

You are missing here in your query `ON ROLE_GROUP.role_id=ROLE_role_id`. instead of ROLE_role_id, use ROLE.role_id

You have to join

1) ROLE_GROUP with ROLE  based on role_id column and

2) ROLE_GROUP with GROUP based on group_id column

3) and use role_name in where clause

```
SELECT ROLE_GROUP.entity_id, GROUP.group_desc
FROM ROLE
     INNER JOIN ROLE_GROUP ON ROLE_GROUP.role_id=ROLE.role_id
     INNER JOIN GROUP ON ROLE_GROUP.group_id=GROUP.group_id
WHERE ROLE.role_name='something';
```